# Magento recalculate in cart

Tags: ajax, magento, cart

I have a `<input type="number"` in my cart. If I'm change count products in cart total price not recalculate that work just if I'm click on button 'recalculate'.

How to automatically recalculate total price in cart on change of products count in 
`<input type="number"` or other?

Comment: Please be clear and elaborate more.your question is not understandable.

Comment: You will have to build this behaviour. i.e. Change the qty and have it auto update the cart total will require a listener on the input field which either resubmits the form.

Comment: The problem is solved